# Loop Adding Records Throws Exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Does anyone know what the proper way of adding records using loops?

I have a system that handles Inventory, Currently I need to be able to Mass Create inventory as creating 50-100 identical items with different ID's would be tedious, What I did was create a MassCreate viewmodel that would essentially take a **StartID** and an **EndID** and a base Inventory Class and in the controller loop through the difference between those two ID's and create a record

The ViewModel isn't an issue and passes the data just fine:

```
public class MassCreateInventoryViewModel
{
    public Inventory InventoryBase { get; set; }
    public int StartID { get; set; }
    public int EndID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Products { get; set; }
}
```

I read somewhere that the `db.SaveChanges()` should be outside of the loop as it should only be called once:

```
    for (int inventoryID = viewModel.StartID; inventoryID <= viewModel.EndID; inventoryID++)
                {
                    Inventory newInventory = new Inventory
                        {
                            InventoryID = inventoryID,
                            ProductID = viewModel.InventoryBase.ProductID,
                            DateEdited = DateTime.Now,
                            EditedByUserID = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId,
                            CustomProperties = viewModel.InventoryBase.CustomProperties
                        };

                    Database.Inventories.Add(newInventory);

                    if (newInventory.CustomProperties != null && newInventory.CustomProperties.Any())
                    {
                        foreach (CustomDataType dt in newInventory.CustomProperties.Select(x => x.DataType).ToList())
                        {
                            Database.Entry(dt).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                        }
                    }

                }
                Database.SaveChanges();
        }
```

But when I try looping, it stores the first record just fine then throws a `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.` Exception.  When I include the `Database.SaveChanges()` after the `Add` method, it throws A `The property 'InventoryID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.` error.

The InventoryID is the `Key` in this table but has been set so that I can input my own ID.

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
[Display(Name = "Inventory ID")]
public new int InventoryID { get; set; }
```

The Custom Property is split into two models, the first being the base class.

```
public class CustomProperty
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CustomPropertyID { get; set; }

    public int CustomDataTypeID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustomDataTypeID")]
    public CustomDataType DataType { get; set; }

    public string PropertyValue { get; set; }
}
```

and the second being the model thats mapped to the database:

```
[Table("CustomInventoryProperty")]
public  class CustomInventoryProperty : CustomProperty
{
    public int InventoryID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("InventoryID")]
    public virtual Inventory Inventory { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do inside the if clause that checks if there are CustomProperties?

You should put `Database.SaveChanges()` outside of the loop, for sure.

Comment: The check is because I have a foreign key to a table CustomTypes that are user defined custom data, and a CustomInventoryProperties table to store their input, the loop is to make sure that CustomTypes does not get modified as I had an issue where everytime you created a new inventory item, it would duplication CustomTypes.

Comment: Can you explain what tables you have in your database, and why? It seems like your data model is not normalized.

Comment: So, why is the CustomerId missing in your code?

Comment: CustomerID is a nullable field because not every inventory Item is associated with a customer.  Technically I shouldn't have put that there, but it was used for testing some things and ended up just stayed there.

Comment: The problem with your code is that you are assigning the CustomProperties list from the BaseInventory class to all new Inventories. You should create a new list of CustomProperty objects with their own CustomPropertyIds and InventoryIds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your for loop with this:

```
var dateEdited = DateTime.Now;
for (int inventoryID = viewModel.StartID; inventoryID <= viewModel.EndID; inventoryID++)
{
    Inventory newInventory = new Inventory
    {
        InventoryID = inventoryID, 
        ProductID = viewModel.InventoryBase.ProductID,
        DateEdited = dateEdited,
        EditedByUserID = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId
    };

    if(viewModel.InventoryBase.CustomProperties != null)  
    {
        newInventory.CustomProperties = new List<CustomProperties>(); 
        foreach(var customProperty in viewModel.InventoryBase.CustomProperties)
        {
           newInventory.CustomProperties.Add(customProperty);
        }
    }

    Database.Inventories.Add(newInventory);
    Database.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I dont get the point of that? the `InventoryBase.CustomProperties` is already a collection, you're basically breaking the collection down and adding it back in?

Comment: Yes, think of each item in that list as a new record in your database table. They all have to have a new primary key, and they should also have an InventoryId.

Comment: In fact, the above code will not work either. Is CustomPropertyId an auto-generated id?

Comment: Yes the PropertyID Is auto-generated. I've added the model to my question

Comment: Either way, your answer did solve my problem, I completely forgot that using the same `CustomProperties` would not create it as a new customProperty. Thanks!